# What is the /odom topic?

Tags: slam, navigation, ros-kinetic, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I'm working on ROS kinetic in Ubuntu 16.04.

I have a simple question; what is the `/odom` topic?

Of course I know it represents the pose of mobile robot at every time, but

is `/odom` topic the result of localization?

When I launch `amcl` node with my robot, in this case,

is it ok if i adopt `/odom` as the robot's localized state by like `EKF` or `UKF`?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/342361/what-is-the-/odom-topic?/) by [kane_choigo](https://answers.ros.org/users/45263/kane_choigo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 195 on 2020-01-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `odom` topic represents more then just the "pose" of the mobile robot. If you check the [message definition of `nav_msgs/Odometry`](http://docs.ros.org/api/nav_msgs/html/msg/Odometry.html) (which is usually used for this kind of message), you see that it also contains the current velocity, as well as the respective uncertainties.

Typically, the odometry describes the "internal" state of the robot, i.e. the integrated position using wheel encoders and, potentially with fused IMU or other sensors measuring internal state. Often it is also used when you fuse a GNSS sensor. Obviously, then you get more in the direction of a localization system then only tracking internal state (see the [wiki for this](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_pose_ekf#robot_pose_ekf-1)).

About `amcl`, though...
`amcl` [neither subscribes nor publishes](http://wiki.ros.org/amcl#Subscribed_Topics) the `odom` topic (as per the wiki). So the answer to

> is it ok if i adopt /odom as the robot's localized state

would be no. Seems the `odom` topic comes from somewhere else. You can use the `amcl_pose` topic for that, or use the published transform.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2020-01-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0